# NotMasterRepositorySchemaException SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'DEV_ODI_REPO.SNP_LOC_REP' doesn't exist. ODI STUDIO OCI MARKETPLACE

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

After loading ODI image from Oracle Marketplace to OCI , when launch odi studio and try to make connection to embedded mysql repostory, the next error is observed:

```
oracle.odi.core.config.NotMasterRepositorySchemaException: ODI-10147: Repository type mismatches.   
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from SNP_LOC_REP]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'DEV_ODI_REPO.SNP_LOC_REP' doesn't exist
    at oracle.odi.core.repository.Repository.getMasterRepository(Repository.java:119)
    at oracle.odi.core.OdiInstance.createMasterRepository(OdiInstance.java:617)
    at oracle.odi.core.OdiInstance.<init>(OdiInstance.java:868)
    at oracle.odi.core.OdiInstance.createInstance(OdiInstance.java:735)
    at oracle.odi.ui.docking.panes.OdiCnxFactory$2.run(OdiCnxFactory.java:247)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.run(ProgressBar.java:961)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from SNP_LOC_REP]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'DEV_ODI_REPO.SNP_LOC_REP' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:694)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:748)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlQuery.execute(SqlQuery.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlQuery.execute(SqlQuery.java:138)
    at oracle.odi.core.repository.support.RepositoryUtils$RepositoryInfoSource.loadRepositoryInfo(RepositoryUtils.java:353)
    at oracle.odi.core.repository.support.RepositoryUtils.loadMasterRepositoryInfo(RepositoryUtils.java:551)
    at oracle.odi.core.repository.Repository.getMasterRepository(Repository.java:95)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'DEV_ODI_REPO.SNP_LOC_REP' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.oracle$1ucp$1jdbc$1proxy$1other$1StatementProxy$2java$1sql$1PreparedStatement$$$Proxy.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at oracle.odi.core.datasource.support.RuntimeClassLoaderDataSourceCreator$StatementInvocationHandler.invoke(RuntimeClassLoaderDataSourceCreator.java:173)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:678)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for configuration to finish and save passwords in wallet that ODI Studio provides.

Monitoring the log:
/home/opc/logs/odiConfigure.log

until you see "Configuration has completed" message.

After that you should open ODI studio and choose Save credentials in a wallet, set a password to the wallet. This is important because the wallet is key for ODI functionality.